# Cannot deploy the ktor server

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, ktor

What kind of problem is that? Does anybody face this? Or anyone knows the solution? I was trying to deploy ktor server using PostgreSQL.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myselfapp"
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:596)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:582)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at com.codewitharfin.db.DatabaseFactory.hikari(DatabaseFactory.kt:25)
    at com.codewitharfin.db.DatabaseFactory.init(DatabaseFactory.kt:11)
    at com.codewitharfin.ApplicationKt$main$1.invoke(Application.kt:10)
    at com.codewitharfin.ApplicationKt$main$1.invoke(Application.kt:9)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.executeModuleFunction(CallableUtils.kt:51)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:332)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:356)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:30)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:319)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:338)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:143)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:277)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:174)
    at com.codewitharfin.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:12)
    at com.codewitharfin.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myselfapp"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:646)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:180)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    ... 21 more
```

I could not find any solution to this, is this some kind of environment problem? But I am giving the password the right here.

Comment: All you posted is stacktrace. Its hard to say whats going on just by looking at that. How does your `application.conf` looks like?

Comment: @nicholasnet bro this is the application file.  https://prnt.sc/216dHrrqJWPd

Comment: @nicholasnet routing file https://prnt.sc/4Y_UYmJLwKAP

Comment: Seems like the password is wrong or there is some problem with permissions.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman i was thinking about that too but could not solve the problem. I think theres somme problems with my PostgreSQL installation and environment setup. not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error when I forgot to mention the password in the URL and also when the password was wrong.

```
private fun hikari(): HikariDataSource{
        val config = HikariConfig()
        config.driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        config.jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql:<database_name_in_lowercase>?user=<username>&password=<password>"
        config.maximumPoolSize = 3
        config.isAutoCommit = false
        config.transactionIsolation = "TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ"
        config.validate()
        return HikariDataSource(config)
    }
```